# Dynamically load items to ExpandableListView using ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

This is my Activity I used to display my items in Expandable List View. At the moment I have hard coded the values which should come to the Expandable List View.

```
String subTotal = getIntent().getStringExtra("subTotal"); // I have these 2 values
String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
```

These are the 2 values I wanna load dynamically.

In the below I have `prepareListData()`, where I have hard coded values to my ExpandableListView.

```
listDataHeader.add("Top 250"); // subTotal
List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
top250.add("The Shawshank"); //price
```

I want to know how to replace these hard coded values with my dynamic values. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

    String subTotal = getIntent().getStringExtra("subTotal"); // i ahve these 2 values
    String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");//

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    getActionBar().setIcon(
            new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Listview Group expanded listener
            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            // Listview on child click listener
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        /*
         * Preparing the list data
         */
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Top 250"); // subTotal

            // Adding child data
            List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
            top250.add("The Shawshank"); //price

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int width = metrics.widthPixels; 

         mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
         mExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));  }

           public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
            // Get the screen's density scale 
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
            return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Your problem is very unclear. It looks as if you only want to replace `top250.add("The Shawshank");` by `top250.add(subTotal);`.

Comment: listDataHeader.add("Top 250"); this loads the headers in the expandable list view. i want to replace that with subTotal. so my main header carries subTotal. when the listview is expanded then i have sub header, at the moment it loads top250.add("The Shawshank"); instead of that i want to load the price variable.

Comment: top250.add(price);  ?

Comment: There are many questions today with similar code and screenshots: Lists with subtotals and stuff like "topping" items... Are you many guys working in the same? Like homework or something?

Comment: yh we are working on our final yr project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this by doing.

```
String price;
String subTotal ;
    subTotal = getIntent().getStringExtra("subTotal");
    price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");

    listDataHeadersubTotal= new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataHeaderPrice= new ArrayList<String>();

    listDataHeadersubTotal.add(subTotal); 
    listDataHeaderPrice.add(price); 

    List<String> price= new ArrayList<String>();
    price.add("The Shawshank"); 
    List<String> subTotal= new ArrayList<String>();
    subTotal.add("The Shawshank");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeadersubTotal.get(0), subTotal);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeaderPrice.get(0), price);
```